# C++ Массив символов: Как скопировать в новый массив 3-и первых буквы последнего слова предложения?

Tags: c++, строки, char

Всем доброго времени суток!

У меня есть массив символов и записанное в нем предложение:
`char str[] = "Ребята, всем привет!";`
Мне нужно скопировать в отдельный массив символов первые три буквы последнего слова, в данном случае **"при"**.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать, и, желательно, максимально легким способом!
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Как вы пытались это сделать и что не получилось?

Comment: самый лёгкий способ: 1. найти позицию последнего пробела. 2. взять три символа после найденной позиции.

Comment: Я пробовал сделать с помощью функции strrchr: `char* last_space = strrchr(str, ' ');`, но проблема в том, что я не знаю, что сделать с результатом ее работы. Она выводит " привет!". 
При этом, если написать так: `cout << last_space - str << endl;`, то программа выведет 12, что соответствует последнему пробелу. Я не понимаю, как это работает, и как это можно использовать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, попробовал с помощью обычного цикла, и все получилось, спасибо! Еще подскажите, как вставить код, чтобы он располагался не в одну строчку, а по-нормальному?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Если максимально лёгким способом,то: создать ещё один массив `str2[]="при"`. Цикл+условие,где будете проверять с главным массивом `str`. Если есть совпадения,то передаёте в пустой массив.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, так и не понял, как это сделать... Когда нажимаю ctrl+k, то срабатывает горячая клавиша для поиска в google.